# Connecting Metamask to private Blockchain created via Puppeth (go-ethereum)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I am using Puppeth provided as part of go-ethereum. It is able to create the containers with geth, all working fine. How to send transaction into this private blockchain via Metamask. I don't see either --rpc flag or rpc port mapping to host. Can someone help connecting metamask to private blockchain created via puppeth. Thanks.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                           NAMES
6a370053beb5        Hello/bootnode      "/bin/sh geth.sh"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          8545-8546/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30303->30303/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30303-30304->30303-30304/udp   Hello_bootnode_1
```

Answer (score 1):

Metamask needs a node to connect through. Puppeth doesn't in its current incarnation expose RPC for any of its deployed nodes (might be a future feature request). As such, your best current bet is to run an own node locally (you can deploy a dashboard via puppeth to see all the connectivity options) and have Metamask use that node.

Longer term it might make sense to integrate INFURA into puppeth too, so among the many services we can deploy, public RPC would also be one.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. One question, in current incarnation how would one send transactions to this private blockchain. Assuming there is a way to send a transaction, otherwise, all the block will be empty. Could you please confirm. Thanks.